# Bounded solution to the heat equation on a strange domain.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find a solution to the heat equation $u_{xx} = u_t$ that is bounded for $0\leq x < \infty$, $-\infty < t < \infty$.

Would $u(x,t) = f(x)$ since if there was any time dependence the solution would blow up for positive or negative time.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hint: Since $-\infty < t < \infty$, at any time the process has already been going on infinitely long, so everything should have settled down to ...

Comment: As Robert Israel has suggested, such a solution can't have any actual time dependence, so you indeed have $u(x,t)=f(x)$. What must then be true about $f$?

Answer (score 0):

Since the solution can not be dependent on time

$u_{xx} = 0$, this means that $u = cx + d$, but since $x$ but $c$ must be zero since $x\in [ 0,\infty)$.